# Casting Booming Blade with an improvised weapon

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, dnd-adventurers-league, improvised-weaponry

In Adventurer's League, can the spell Booming Blade be casted using an improvised weapon (a shield)?

Comment: It is a different question since here is used a non simple or martial weapon, but maybe the answer is the same